# Has anyone noticed a problem with Safari closing down when selecting a print option on some websites

Tags: safari, printing

I have been on two websites recently using Safari; pressing the print document option on the website caused Safari to close down.  Very annoying as I had just submitted a whole set of company accounts data and I needed the printout of the image created by the website.  Is this a known problem with Safari?  One of the sites was a UK government site so I'd expect it to be robust.
Anything one can do?  I am using Monterey and Safari 15.2.

Comment: This is not normal behaviour and there's not much information to troubleshoot. Remember that there's a plethora of web-server platforms out there, and not all of them are browser and/or OS agnostic. This particular site may work great for IE or Edge on Windows, but be buggy for Safari on macOS. Are you limited to Safari? If not, try with Google Chrome or Firefox. If you are required to use Safari, enable the Develop menu and change the user agent to have Safari respond to web server browser type queries impersonating other browsers.

Comment: All the UK Gov sites I've ever had to use have been notoriously Mac-unfriendly :\ Never tried to print from one, though. [Just tried printing from TfL ULEZ payment - no issues.]